# Is there a universal statement for the construction of global Proj?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, sheaf-theory, schemes

Let $X$ be a scheme and $\mathcal{A}$ be a sheaf of $\mathbb{Z}_{\ge 0}$-graded $\mathcal{O}_X$-algebras.

From the data above there is a construction which gives the "global Proj" $Proj \mathcal{ A} \to X$ which satisfies that the pullback along any affine open subset $SpecB=U \subset X$ is the (usual) Proj construction of the graded $B$-algebra $\Gamma(U,\mathcal{A})$.

I've went through several proofs of this construction over the past few months and was rather patient hoping that eventually I'll be convinced. Sadly though I'm still confused just as badly as I was on day 1. My problem is that all the **ad-hoc arguments about gluing don't stick with me in the long run since I'm not entirely sure what object is being constructed and what properties are being verified.** For the main example of what my problem is look at [the following question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1778462/elegant-formalism-for-gluing-spaces-over-open-subsets-vakil-17-2-b)

> Suppose I choose an affine cover (assuming $X$ is qcqs) and construct $Proj \mathcal{A}$ via a gluing. Suppose now I choose a different cover, what garauntees me that the result will be the same? Moreover why do pullbacks behave nicely as in the above description?

Here is an attempt of mine to give a universal construction which might solve the issue:

The following limit (assuming it exists) seems natural from the point of view of gluing a space over a basis of open sets (the limit is indexed over the category of coverings with refinements as morphisms):

$$\lim_{\text{all covers}} \text{coeq} \{ \coprod Proj \Gamma(U_{ij}, \mathcal{A})\rightrightarrows \coprod Proj \Gamma(U_{j}, \mathcal{A}) \}$$

> Is this limit isomorphic to the global Proj of $\mathcal{A}$? Perhaps
>   after imposing some reasonable conditions on $X$?

Comment: Just to be sure, *all covers* means *covers by affine opens*, right? If so, then this inverse limit should be just the coequaliser for the open cover consisting of all affine opens. And then something weird is about to happen if $\mathcal{A} = \mathcal{O}_X$ and when some $U_{ij}$ is not affine.

Comment: @Ben I think I want *all covers* to means ***all** covers* and not only affine ones. I revised the question to reflect some of the motivation and further confusion I have about this.

Comment: I probably don't understand the question (certainly I don't understand this stuff about co-sheaves). But you do know that $\operatorname{Spec} \mathscr A$ has a universal property, right? This should be given in the Stacks Project and EGA. In these two sources (at least in the second edition of EGA) the existence is probably shown using Grothendieck's representability criterion.

Comment: @Hoot Yes. I know about the universal property of Spec and that's why I added that intro sentence. I should probably turn this into a question about global proj.

Comment: There is also a universal property of $\operatorname{Proj}$ but it's a bit harder to state. See http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01NS To me this seems to answer the first part of the question.

Comment: @Hoot Do you think there's a convincing statement one can say about why pullbacks to affine behave as you want them without going through this universal property? I specifically have in mind the section in Vakil's book which treats this (In case you're familiar with this book). I've never understood how to solve that section in a convincing way.

Comment: I guess I don't understand. To me "by the universal property" seems like the best possible answer to the question of why something holds.

Comment: @Hoot I completely agree (and will certainly go through this section in STACKS). I was just wondering if the section in Vakil's book (which got me on this route in the first place) can actually be solved in way I can understand. Thanks anyways!

Comment: You mean the construction here? http://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/01NM I agree that it's a little weird. It seems to me like you want a universal property that makes this construction the obvious thing to do? Or glues the "local" functors together somehow.

Comment: After the edit I have to ask: a) maybe you prefer the glueing-free construction in Eisenbud-Harris, describing it as the space of prime ideal sheaves?--b) I don't understand why glueing all specs over all affine opens should be ad-hoc. I consider this more natural than trying to glue with respect to any cover--c) does the adjunction "$\operatorname{Hom}_X(T,\operatorname{Spec}(\mathcal{A}))=\operatorname{Hom}_{\mathcal{O}_{X}-Alg.}(\mathcal{A},f_*\mathcal{O}_T)$ for each $f\colon T\to X$" count as a universal property?

Comment: @Ben You're completely correct that there's a universal route for the global spec case and that's why I phrased the question the way I did. I see now that it's only more confusing this way. I'll probably chage that tomorrow morning. In the mean time I've added a link to my previous question about this: :http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1778462/elegant-formalism-for-gluing-spaces-over-open-subsets-vakil-17-2-b

Comment: @SaalHardali I have TeXed notes on a glueing free construction of the global spec which I could send you. However, they are written in german.

Comment: @Hanno Thanks, though I'm already familiar with one for global spec by considering prime ideal sheaves. Again I should have probably avoided asking about global spec.